# Opening an embedded HelloSign Signature in custom iframe

Tags: hellosign-api

I've built out a system where my users can sign HelloSign signatures [created with embedded signature request](https://developers.hellosign.com/api/reference/operation/signatureRequestCreateEmbedded/) on the backend.

In the frontend, I'm using the [hellosign-embedded](https://github.com/hellosign/hellosign-embedded) library and using it like this to open the included iframe:

```
const helloSignClient = new HelloSign({ clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_HELLO_SIGN_CLIENT_ID });
// ....
const [generateEmbeddedSignUrl] = useMutation<
    IGenerateEmbeddedSignUrlResponse,
    IGenerateEmbeddedSignUrlVars
  >(GenerateEmbeddedSignUrl, {
    onCompleted: ({ generateEmbeddedSignUrl }) => {
      if (generateEmbeddedSignUrl.error) {
        return message.error(
          `Error generating signature URL: ${
            generateEmbeddedSignUrl.error.userMessage || generateEmbeddedSignUrl.error.description
          }`
        );
      }

      if (generateEmbeddedSignUrl.embeddedSignUrl.signUrl) {
        // Embedded URL is generated. Start Signing with the Hello Sign SDK
        helloSignClient.open(generateEmbeddedSignUrl.embeddedSignUrl.signUrl, {
          // testMode will be true on staging or development, false on production
          testMode: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? false : true,
        });
      }
    },
    onError: (error) => message.error(error),
  });
```

Now that I have new requirements, I want to place this hellosign signature into a modal, where the modal will have the list next to the iframe (removed some info because sensitive info):

[image]

I'm trying to do something like this but it seems that there's some conflicting logic where the hellosign library will create its own modal/iframe and controlled like that. I'm not sure how to override this behavior.

I tried taking my generated sign URL and placing that into its own iframe but I get an error:

```
Something went wrong!
Your request seems to have been malformed and returned the following error:

→ Missing parameter: client_id
```

Which I assume is me missing `client_id` from the library:

```
const helloSignClient = new HelloSign({ clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_HELLO_SIGN_CLIENT_ID });
```

I guess my questions are: how do I achieve the mockup that I was given? Is it possible to open an embedded signature link in my own custom modal/iframe? Do I have to take the CSS route and override some behaviors? How do I open an embedded link without needing a `client_id` or using this library?

Answer (score -1):

I'm an API Support engineer at Dropbox Sign,

We strongly recommend using our [Embedded library](https://github.com/hellosign/hellosign-embedded) to implement the iframe, as implementing that will ensure that you have implemented everything required to load Dropbox Sign.